# Specifying initial field values for ModelForm associated with inherited models

Tags: django, django-forms, model-inheritance

**Question** : What is the recommended way to specify an initial value for fields if one uses model inheritance and each child model needs to have different default values when rendering a `ModelForm`?

Take for example the following models where `CompileCommand` and `TestCommand` both need different initial values when rendered as `ModelForm`.

```
# ------ models.py
class ShellCommand(models.Model):
    command   = models.Charfield(_("command"), max_length=100)
    arguments = models.Charfield(_("arguments"), max_length=100)

class CompileCommand(ShellCommand):
    # ... default command should be "make"

class TestCommand(ShellCommand):
    # ... default: command = "make", arguments = "test"
```

I am aware that one can used the `initial={...}` argument when instantiating the form, however I would rather store the initial values within the context of the model (or at least within the associated ModelForm).

#### My current approach

What I'm doing at the moment is storing an initial value dict within `Meta`, and checking for it in my views.

```
# ----- forms.py
class CompileCommandForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CompileCommand
        initial_values = {"command":"make"}

class TestCommandForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TestCommand
        initial_values = {"command":"make", "arguments":"test"}


# ------ in views
FORM_LOOKUP = { "compile": CompileCommandFomr, "test": TestCommandForm }
CmdForm = FORM_LOOKUP.get(command_type, None)
# ...
initial = getattr(CmdForm, "initial_values", {})
form = CmdForm(initial=initial)
```

This feels too much like a hack. I am eager for a more generic / better way to achieve this. Suggestions appreciated.

#### Updated solution (looks promising)

I now have the following in `forms.py` which allow me to set `Meta.default_initial_values` without needing extra boilerplate code in views. Default values are used if user does not specify `initial={...}` args.

```
class ModelFormWithDefaults(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if hasattr(self.Meta, "default_initial_values"):
            kwargs.setdefault("initial", self.Meta.default_initial_values)
        super(ModelFormWithDefaults, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class TestCommandForm(ModelFormWithDefaults):
    class Meta:
        model = TestCommand
        default_initial_values = {"command":"make", "arguments":"test"}
```

Comment: Did you try to overwrite the constructor and set the new defaults/init values?

Comment: I have had much luck with overriding `Models.__init__()` (yet), while overriding the constructor for each `ModelForm` would end up with code far bussier that what I have currently.

Comment: Updated question to show what I've tried.

Comment: about your edit, I think you have to check that kwargs.get('data') is None and then do something like self.fields["command"].initial = "make"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see that much use in setting initial_values on form's meta if you then have to send to the form init.

I would rather create a subclass of ModelForm that overrides the constructor method and then use that subclass as parent class of the other forms.

e.g.

```
class InitialModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    #here you override the constructor
    pass

class TestCommandForm(InitialModelForm):
    #form meta

class CompileCommandForm(InitialModelForm):
    #form meta
```

Comment: Agreed. That's pretty much along the lines of what I ended up with after some filddling about. Updated question to show solution I settled with.